# Docusign: Is there a way for senders to fill in information before sending the template out without editing the layout of said doucment?

Tags: docusignapi

I was wondering if there was a way for senders to edit fields without modifying the template nor signing it. This can of course be solved by having the sender first send it to themselves, but this complicates the workflow. Also, the data that is going to be filled in is not stored in our system, so it cannot be filled in automatically.

We're essentially looking for a Recipient Preview mode for the sender prior to envelope creation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Generate the envelope as a draft, then use a Create Sender View call and redirect the sender to the url that is returned. From there, the sender can populate fields as needed.

Request URL: `POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender`

Body:

```
{
  "returnUrl": "https://www.example.com/"
}
```

The call is documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender

Comment: Sorry for not quite understanding, but I don't see in that documentation how to generate the envelope as a draft. We already have a createSender view implemented, but it currently leads to a page to fully edit the document which allows for creating and deleting information rather than just filling it out. How do we generate the envelope as a draft at the start?

Comment: To generate an envelope as a Draft, you set the 'status' to 'created' instead of 'sent'. 
The Sender View always allows full editing. If you want to restrict editing to only allow filling in tag data, you'll need to send it to them first so they access it as a signer.
You might consider editing the base template to set the tags to have: Sender Permissions > Restrict Changes & Mandatory.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the edits! The permissions seems like a good fix for what we have to work with.